# Need help debugging Pytorch implementation of a Siamese Neural Network

Tags: pytorch, siamese-network

I put together the following Pytorch implementation a simple Siamese neural network with a binary classification dataset of two concentric rings in 2D, but my training loss seems to oscillate between 0 and the contrastive loss margin.  Would love to hear any advice or suggestions to help get the training loss to 0.  Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch import optim
import torch.nn.functional as F

def set_device():
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        return "cuda"
    elif torch.backends.mps.is_available():
        return "mps"
    else:
        return "cpu"

def create_data(size=1000):
    data_lst = []
    target = 0
    while target < size:
        x = torch.rand(2) * 6 + 1
        radius_sq = torch.square(x[0] - 4) + torch.square(x[1] - 4)
        if 1 <= radius_sq <= 9:
            if radius_sq < 3.6:
                y = torch.tensor(0)
            elif radius_sq > 4.4:
                y = torch.tensor(1)
            else:
                continue
            data_lst.append((x, y))
            target += 1
    return data_lst

def plot_data(datapoints):
    outside_points = [point[0].numpy() for point in datapoints if point[1] == 1]
    inside_points = [point[0].numpy() for point in datapoints if point[1] == 0]
    outside = np.vstack(outside_points)
    inside = np.vstack(inside_points)
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    plt.scatter(outside[:, 0], outside[:, 1])
    plt.scatter(inside[:, 0], inside[:, 1], c='red')
    plt.show()

def split_data(raw_data):
    data_size = len(raw_data)
    train_size = int(0.8 * data_size)
    training_data = data[:train_size]
    testing_data = data[train_size:]
    return training_data, testing_data

class SNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128, 1024),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(1024, 256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(256, 64),
            nn.ReLU()
        )

    def forward(self, input1, input2):
        output1 = self.fc1(input1)
        output2 = self.fc1(input2)
        return output1, output2

class ContrastiveLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, margin=0.2):
        super().__init__()
        self.margin = margin

    def forward(self, output1, output2, same_label):
        euclidean_distance = F.pairwise_distance(output1, output2)
        contrastive_loss = torch.mean(same_label * torch.square(euclidean_distance) +
                                      (1-same_label) * max(0, self.margin**2 -
                                                           torch.square(euclidean_distance)))
        return contrastive_loss

def train_model(net):
    net.to(device)
    for epoch in range(10):
        for i in range(0, len(train_data), 2):
            input1, label1 = train_data[i]
            input2, label2 = train_data[i + 1]
            input1, label1 = input1.to(device), label1.to(device)
            input2, label2 = input2.to(device), label2.to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            output1, output2 = net(input1, input2)
            loss = criterion(output1, output2, int(label1 == label2))
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            if i != 0 and i % 100 == 0:
                print(f'Epoch={epoch + 1} Iter={i + 1:5d} Loss={loss.item():.3f}')

    print('Finished training')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    device = set_device()
    data = create_data()
    plot_data(data)
    train_data, test_data = split_data(data)

    model = SNNModel()
    criterion = ContrastiveLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001)
    train_model(model)
```